# multithreading- face recognition from streaming of ip-camera

Tags: python, keras, jupyter, opencv

I am trying to make ipcamera face recognition program.   For reducing the delay of FPS, separated capture.read() part from the main thread. However strangely, an error is occurring in the looping block. How can I correct the codes?

----error messages----

```
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-1-9057dfacb896> in <module>
    149 
    150 if __name__ == "__main__":
--> 151     main()

<ipython-input-1-9057dfacb896> in main()
    146 def main():
    147     face = FaceIdentify(precompute_features_file="./data/precompute_features.pickle")
--> 148     face.detect_face()
    149 
    150 if __name__ == "__main__":

<ipython-input-1-9057dfacb896> in detect_face(self)
    111 
    112 
--> 113             gray = cv2.cvtColor(self.frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    114             faces = face_cascade.detectMultiScale(
    115                 gray,

AttributeError: 'FaceIdentify' object has no attribute 'frame'
```

----codes----

```
class FaceIdentify(object):

    CASE_PATH = "haarcascade_frontalface_alt.xml"

    def __new__(cls, precompute_features_file=None):
        if not hasattr(cls, 'instance'):
            cls.instance = super(FaceIdentify, cls).__new__(cls)
        return cls.instance

    def __init__(self, precompute_features_file=None, src=0):
        self.face_size = 224
        self.precompute_features_map = load_stuff(precompute_features_file)
        print("Loading VGG Face model...")
        self.model = VGGFace(model='resnet50',
                             include_top=False,
                             input_shape=(224, 224, 3),
                             pooling='avg')  # pooling: None, avg or max
        print("Loading VGG Face model done")
        self.capture=cv2.VideoCapture(src)
        self.thread=Thread(target=self.update)
        self.thread.daemon=True
        self.thread.start()

    def update(self):
        while True:
            if self.capture.isOpened():
                (self.status, self.frame) = self.capture.read()
            time.sleep(.01)





    def draw_label(cls, image, point, label, font=cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX,
                   font_scale=1, thickness=2):
        size = cv2.getTextSize(label, font, font_scale, thickness)[0]
        x, y = point
        cv2.rectangle(image, (x, y - size[1]), (x + size[0], y), (255, 0, 0), cv2.FILLED)
        cv2.putText(image, label, point, font, font_scale, (255, 255, 255), thickness)

    def crop_face(self, imgarray, section, margin=20, size=224):

        img_h, img_w, _ = imgarray.shape
        if section is None:
            section = [0, 0, img_w, img_h]
        (x, y, w, h) = section
        margin = int(min(w, h) * margin / 100)
        x_a = x - margin
        y_a = y - margin
        x_b = x + w + margin
        y_b = y + h + margin
        if x_a < 0:
            x_b = min(x_b - x_a, img_w - 1)
            x_a = 0
        if y_a < 0:
            y_b = min(y_b - y_a, img_h - 1)
            y_a = 0
        if x_b > img_w:
            x_a = max(x_a - (x_b - img_w), 0)
            x_b = img_w
        if y_b > img_h:
            y_a = max(y_a - (y_b - img_h), 0)
            y_b = img_h
        cropped = imgarray[y_a: y_b, x_a: x_b]
        resized_img = cv2.resize(cropped, (size, size), interpolation=cv2.INTER_AREA)
        resized_img = np.array(resized_img)
        return resized_img, (x_a, y_a, x_b - x_a, y_b - y_a)

    def identify_face(self, features, threshold=100):
        distances = []
        for person in self.precompute_features_map:
            person_features = person.get("features")
            distance = sp.spatial.distance.euclidean(person_features, features)
            distances.append(distance)
        min_distance_value = min(distances)
        min_distance_index = distances.index(min_distance_value)
        if min_distance_value < threshold:
            return self.precompute_features_map[min_distance_index].get("name")
        else:
            return "Unknown person"

    def detect_face(self):
        face_cascade = cv2.CascadeClassifier(self.CASE_PATH)


        while True:


            gray = cv2.cvtColor(self.frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
            faces = face_cascade.detectMultiScale(
                gray,
                scaleFactor=1.2,
                minNeighbors=10,
                minSize=(64, 64)
            )

            face_imgs = np.empty((len(faces), self.face_size, self.face_size, 3))
            for i, face in enumerate(faces):
                face_img, cropped = self.crop_face(self.frame, face, margin=10, size=self.face_size)
                (x, y, w, h) = cropped
                cv2.rectangle(self.frame, (x, y), (x + w, y + h), (255, 200, 0), 2)
                face_imgs[i, :, :, :] = face_img
            if len(face_imgs) > 0:
                # generate features for each face
                features_faces = self.model.predict(face_imgs)
                predicted_names = [self.identify_face(features_face) for features_face in features_faces]
            # draw results
            for i, face in enumerate(faces):
                label = "{}".format(predicted_names[i])
                self.draw_label(self.frame, (face[0], face[1]), label)

            cv2.imshow('Keras Faces', self.frame)
            if cv2.waitKey(5) == 27:  # ESC key press
                break
        # When everything is done, release the capture
        video_capture.release()
        cv2.destroyAllWindows()
        cv2.waitKey(1)



def main():
    face = FaceIdentify(precompute_features_file="./data/precompute_features.pickle")
    face.detect_face()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: The call to `self.frame` on the line `cv2.imshow('Keras Faces', self.frame)` may be part of the problem You haven't defined or initialized`self.frame anywhere

Answer (score 1):

in `detect_face()` you have a line `gray = cv2.cvtColor(self.frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)` -- and `self.frame` is not declared anywhere in the code. you may want to fix that. usually the best place for the class variable declaration is `__init__()` function.

Comment: Thank you for your response. I am a beginner in python. Can you tell me how can I declare or initialize self.frame in the __init__() function ?

Comment: @hyungookAn put `(self.status, self.frame) = self.capture.read()` somewhere after `self.capture=cv2.VideoCapture(src)`

Comment: I put (self.status, self.frame) = self.capture.read() just below self.capture=cv2.VideoCapture(src) but same error occured. " AttributeError: 'FaceIdentify' object has no attribute 'frame'. " Actually (self.status, self.frame) = self.capture.read() was put inside the 'update' function which is assigned as a separate thread. Was that a problem?. Can you give me some more advices?  Thank you.

Comment: @hyungookAn in `__init__`, please remove the parentheses from `(self.status, self.frame)`, so it becomes `self.status, self.frame`

Comment: I removed the parentheses and it works well. Thank you so much for your help.

Comment: @hyungookAn if you find my answer useful, you may accept and / or upvote =)